# How to fetch attributes from textarea content with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, svg

Im trying to make a little page that fetches a certain attribute from a svg path container.

I have this simple form where i will type in my  code into a textarea form which begins like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eq1kN.png

I then want to put this path code into my textarea form, and when i click "Create Game", it will append/html it into my svg container like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPJFv.png

SVG Container looks like this:

```
<svg id="svgmap" version="1.1">
    <g id="pathdata">

    </g>
</svg>
```

I then need the path´s i enter to go into that g container.

Im able to inject the textarea into a simple div with jquery, but im unable to select the g container and insert into that. Also when trying to select the inserted path, im unable to do so.

The main purpose of all this is to display what svg paths i enter, and to put a specific path attribute into an array for further use.

Hope someone knows the issue.

Thanks in advance
Jesper

Answer (score 0):

not complete code but you can try something like this :

JS

```
var raw = $('#raw').val();//get value of your textarea
var array = []; // result store here
var rePattern = /([A-Z]{1}[0-9,.]{0,})/gi; //regex to match

raw.replace(rePattern, function(match, text, urlId){
    array.push(match);
});

console.log(array);
```

HTML

```
<svg id="svgmap" version="1.1">
    <g id="pathdata">

    </g>
</svg>
<textarea id="raw">L12.12,454.89M54.12,48.65</textarea>
```

js fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/poignant_benjamin/qp60kf8h/

Comment: Thats actually almost the opposite of what i need mate. I need to enter values into the textarea by pasting in the svg path codes. 
Then when i click a button, that path html ,will be sent to the svg container, which will then draw the svg paths. 

Then from there, i need to fetch the path containers "d" attribute for futher use. Hope it made sense